# What's going on with my UV Map

Tags: uv

This is a Cheetah mesh. I double checked that the seams were marked correctly and I don't think I'm missing anything. Should the seams be blue? Aren't they usually red?

[image]

Then when I unwrap, my UV map turns out like this.
[image]

It's as if the whole mesh is stretched out for some reason. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: yep seams should be red. Looks like you *Marked Sharp* not *Mark Seam*.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I accidentally marked sharp instead of seams.